# how to parse this json object returned from an api call using c#

Tags: c#, api, json.net

{
"0x7d1afa7b718fb893db30a3abc0cfc608aacfebb0": {
"usd": 0.889768
}
}

above is what i get back from coin gecko's api
i believe this is a dictionary of an object that has a variable named 'usd' of type decimal??

this is what my code looks like for attempting to extract the data

```
    public class dm_Testing
    {
        public decimal usd { get; set; }
    }

    public class dm_Return_MaticPrice
    {
        public Dictionary<string, dm_Testing> MaticUSD { get; set; } 
            = new Dictionary<string, dm_Testing>();
    }
```

this is what i am using in the process

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(_url_MaticPrice);
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

//Converting to correct object from json string
string nVal = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();

dm_Return_MaticPrice nTesting = new dm_Return_MaticPrice();
nTesting = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dm_Return_MaticPrice>(nVal);
```

how ever the application does not break is just give me a 0 and not the 'usd' value returned from the api. any insight of how to correctly parse this data into my model using c#?

Comment: Please provide the value of `_url_MaticPrice` as well.

Comment: When pasting the JSON here: https://json2csharp.com/ the code looks different from yours. (there are other online converters too, this one is just the one I tried today)

Comment: In addition: Copy the JSON (string), open Visual Studio, create a new (dummy) class, click on Edit (toolbar), Click on Paste Special and Paste JSON As Classes. It generates C# classes based on the given JSON.

Comment: it's the url address of the api call

Answer (score 0):

Another online converter (https://app.quicktype.io/) did do almost the same:

```
namespace Stackoverflow
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    using System.Text.Json;
    using System.Text.Json.Serialization;
    using System.Globalization;

    public partial class Rates
    {
        [JsonPropertyName("0x7d1afa7b718fb893db30a3abc0cfc608aacfebb0")]
        public The0X7D1Afa7B718Fb893Db30A3Abc0Cfc608Aacfebb0 The0X7D1Afa7B718Fb893Db30A3Abc0Cfc608Aacfebb0 { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class The0X7D1Afa7B718Fb893Db30A3Abc0Cfc608Aacfebb0
    {
        [JsonPropertyName("usd")]
        public double Usd { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And, I knew it was somewhere in Visual Studio, but I can never remember where, but @Odrai remined us:

> In addition: Copy the JSON (string), open Visual Studio, create a new (dummy) class, click on Edit (toolbar), Click on Paste Special and Paste JSON As Classes. It generates a C# class based on the given JSON.

Comment: okay im about to try this

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Newtonsoft.Json you can extract the usd value with one line.

```
var str = "{ \"0x7d1afa7b718fb893db30a3abc0cfc608aacfebb0\": { \"usd\": 0.889768 } }";
decimal? usd = JObject.Parse(str)?.First?.First["usd"]?.Value<decimal>();
```